# why can not disable datetime required attributes MVC model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Every thing is ok This model:

```
[Range(1, 24, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Hour")]
public int? val1{ get; set; }
```

on the other hand; this returns invalid error. if i dont write any value in EndDateTime:

```
public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(myinstance);
```

return invalid enddatetime But i give nullable value property. i gave empty value on enddatetime, but return to me invalid enddatetime error.How to solve it?

Comment: please can show us the code that for "gave empty value on enddatetime,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the database accepts nulls.  The ModelState will not return valid if the value does not pass the validation.  Add a default value that will pass the validation.